# Куда поместить определение интерфейсов в golang проекте?

Tags: golang, архитектура

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как организовать программу на Go?
Имеется интерфейс Send() который используется в двух пакетах у которых один общий пакет.

```
type Sender interface {
    Send()
}

- app
  - service
  - handler
  - senders

// services/someService.go
func someService(s Sender) {}

// handlers/someHandler.go
func someHandler(s Sender) {}
```

Вопрос, куда поместить объявление интерфейса Sender? Есть два варианта

- сделать в app файл interfaces.go и определить общие интерфейсы приложения
- или же в каждом пакете services and handlers определить свой интерфейс Sender - фактически копии друг друга

Ведь в go рекомендуют определять интерфейсы по месту их использования.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A little copying is better than a little dependency.
>
> https://go-proverbs.github.io/

Даже в стандартной библиотеке есть места, где те же `io.Reader` или `fmt.Stringer` переопределены, чтобы избежать ненужной зависимости от других пакетов. Если ваш интерфейс маленький, скопировать его не составит труда, а если он большой, то есть вероятность, что в будущем одному модулю понадобятся одни методы, а другому - другие.